# Bolding a cell in PHPExcel leaves it selected

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am updating an Excel5 formatted spreadsheet with PHPExcel.  After retrieving and setting some cells I have the following code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A$total_row:N$total_row")->getFont()->setBold(true);
```

The range of cells does get bolded. But it also is selected when the spreadsheet is opened in Excel, which I don't want. As a workaround I ended up selecting cell A1 by bolding it, but what is the correct way to select a cell in PHPExcel?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The worksheet's setSelectedCells() method:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setSelectedCells('A1');
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked perfectly. I had searched the Word version of the documentation and there was no mention of it. After your post, I found it in the HTML docs.

Comment: The word docs don't cover every single method call. That's what the ALI docs are for

Comment: ALI should have been API (perils of typing it on a kindle)